# week wise date in sql

Tags: c#, sql

I am developing an application in C# .net in which user will select a year and I want to show him week wise dates.

e.g. for year 2013

```
Week  Start Date    End Date
------------------------------
1     2013-01-01    2013-01-06
```

it goes on till 31st Dec 2013

I have already created a stored procedure using which I get above output.

But for the first week it should start from Monday which is 2013-12-31.

Please help.

Regards,

Zuber Kazi

Comment: Why not use the `DateTimePicker` ?

Comment: Please, check with day of week in monday or not.

Comment: can you post the stored proc you used to generate this output?

Comment: Why are you doing this in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

use following logic to decide first day of first week

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME=CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-01-'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE())) )
SELECT DATEADD(d,(DATEPART(dw,@Date)-2)*-1,@Date )
```

This will help you to decide which index is for any week day.
Index starts from 1 and from Sunday

```
SELECT (DATEPART(dw,@Date))
```

Comment: Dear Bharat Thanx for the help. It is working from Monday to Saturday but for Sunday it takes next day as start.

Comment: @user2042955 I think this is possible to set the first day of the week

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this in SQL? Take a method and keep this method in `page_load`

```
            DateTime da = DateTime.Now;
            int offset = da.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;
            DateTime lastMonday = da.AddDays(-offset);
            Label1.Text = lastMonday.ToShortDateString();
            Label2.Text = lastMonday.AddDays(+1).ToShortDateString();
            Label3.Text = lastMonday.AddDays(+2).ToShortDateString();
            Label4.Text = lastMonday.AddDays(+3).ToShortDateString();
            Label5.Text = lastMonday.AddDays(+4).ToShortDateString();
            Label6.Text = lastMonday.AddDays(+5).ToShortDateString();
            Label7.Text = lastMonday.AddDays(+6).ToShortDateString();
```